# Create Report from list of objects in .net without saving them in database!

Tags: c#, .net, list, crystal-reports

I want to create a report of a list of objects that don't persist in db in VS2008 C#!
When I use Crystal Report, I should reference the report to a special Table in DB or an object in Application. But I want to report from a non-persistent list which is a list of objects from a class.

Comment: Yadollah, there's no such thing as C#.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in scribd.com/doc/24689401/Crystal-Reports

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to push a dataset into a report table like this
when you have a ReportDocument...

Report.Database.Tables["Customer"]SetDataSource (dataSet);

However, I'm not sure whether this is possible without having a datasource set for the reportdocument first. It is worth a shot I guess.